# Elasticsearch GET query not returning results by mentioning document id in the GET call

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a elasticsearch query and make a GET call by passing the document id to get the expected document.

My expected results are coming wrong, why? It would be great if anyone can help me out in this.

**Example:**

```
GET /recipe_index/_doc/1011524443 
 {}
```

**Result:**

```
{"_index":"es_recipe_a","_type":"_doc","_id":"1011524443","_version":8,"result":"updated","_shards":{"total":2,"successful":1,"failed":0}}
```

Answer (score 0):

official only say `GET /index/_doc/id` to get a JSON document or
`HEAD /index/_doc/id` to check for the existence.
i think use `GET /index/_doc/id` with body is a problem,it should throw Exception.

Answer (score -1):

It is because you have set `{}` in the query and elasticsearch think it as update query and update it. This is your query which answers correctly

```
GET /recipe_index/_doc/1011524443
```

Also you can use this query:

```
GET recipe_index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "term": {
      "_id": {
        "value": "1011524443"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer，i think elasticsearch use Update Api to update document and this is a Get request , elasticsearch may not make Get request to Post

Comment: i want to find the official documents where to explain this question

Comment: Just to be 100% correct, it's not an update (which happens through the `_update` endpoint), but an indexation of a new version of the document. And since you've passed `{}` your document with id `1011524443` is now empty

Comment: @Leeh which version of ES are you using? because in the recent versions of ES this behavior has been corrected.

Comment: elasticsearch version is 7.2.0

Answer (score -1):

You're missing to use correct index name. As per your results:

```
{"_index":"es_recipe_a","_type":"_doc","_id":"1011524443","_version":8,"result":"updated","_shards":{"total":2,"successful":1,"failed":0}}
```

it shows that you're querying inside `es_recipe_a` index.

In your GET query, you're mentioning `recipe_index` index.

Hence, if you will run this query:

```
GET /recipe_index/_doc/1011524443
```

it will not run because the index name is different.

**Final Solution**:

Try this:

```
GET /es_recipe_a/_doc/1011524443
```

You will get the expected results.